# Toggle div in and out off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to toggle a div out of screen partially, and back in screen fully. This code tells how far "sidebar" is to move offscreen. But in my case this functionality has a problem, due to media queries applied to sidebar width. Therefore I need the code not to state how far over sidebar will move, but how much of sidebar will be left onscreen in pixels. [The demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/14/) (with the media queries).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $("#sidebar").animate({
          left: '0%'
        });
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#sidebar").animate({
          left: '-55%'
        });
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/sysfuvu1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#togglebutton").click(function() {
    var $container = $('#myToggleDiv');
    $container.toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple maths:

Say you want the side bar to have 40px left on the screen, and the rest hidden. So you want to move it left by (width - 40). I.e.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $("#sidebar").animate({
                    left: '0%'
            });
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $("#sidebar").animate({
                left: - ($("#sidebar").width() - 40)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#toggle {
    width: 10%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-right: 6.5%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR<input type="button" value="Toggle" id="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thank you!! May I add one more question. After toggling sidebar down to 40 px left in screen, when I scale the browser window larger or smaller the amount of pixels left in screen for sidebar changes due to the media queries. How can keep I keep it at 40px in screen in sidebar's collapsed state? Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/17/  In its expanded state its width must vary depending on window size.

Comment: In the else statement to hide it, try setting the width of sidebar to a fixed value, then changing it back to be resizable in the if. It will remain fixed when it's hidden. Though it is a bit of a hack. http://jsfiddle.net/100pvu95/18/ I put 500 in the example, but you can work it out what it should be.

Comment: Thanks again! Closer, but not quite there. Yes , in collapsed state the sidebar maintains the same amount in view when scaling the window. Great! But when expanding sidebar again it does not go back to the width set within the appropriate media querie, but goes to 100% of the window.

Comment: My bad, I hardcoded 100% there. Just change the value. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting negative left value in percentages, use the width of your element and set the left value according to the width of your element:

```
$("#sidebar").animate({
    left: '-' + ($("#sidebar").width()*0.55) + 'px'
});
```

Check this snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#toggle").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $("#sidebar").animate({
        left: '0'
      });
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $("#sidebar").animate({
        left: '-' + ($("#sidebar").width()*0.55) + 'px'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#toggle {
    width: 10%;
    height: 40%;
    margin-right: 6.5%;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR<input type="button" value="Toggle" id="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: Good idea to add px at the end, I forgot about that.